# How to implement the algorithm for HashCash in Go (type conversion issues)?

Tags: hash, casting, bit-manipulation, go

I've been trying to implement the HashCash algorithm in Go! For those of you who don't know -

> HashCash is a method to stop spam. Basically, a header is constructed of some environment variables known both to the client and server (email, timestamp etc.). A random nonce is appended to the end of the header. The client tries to bruteforce a partial hash collision (e.g. where the first *x* bits are 0) by changing the nonce.
>
> HashCash works because it's not as expensive to find **partial** hash collisions. When the server receives this header, they verify the information in it (so it can be used only for one session) and compute the resulting hash. If the first *x* bits are 0, then a good amount of time has been expended on the client's machine, computing the collision (which wouldn't happen on a spambot)

For me, I'm just wanting to write a program which finds the time it takes for a client to find a partial hash collision of *x* bits.

I wrote this code which will return true/false if the *int64* has a hash collision of *x* bits.

```
func partialAllZeroes (zeroCount uint8, val int64) (bool, os.Error) {
    setBitString := "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
    unsetBitString := "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    setBitString = setBitString[0:zeroCount-1]
    unsetBitString = unsetBitString[0:zeroCount-1]
    
    zeroTest, e := strconv.Btoi64(setBitString, 2) // 64 0bits
    zeroes, e   := strconv.Btoi64(unsetBitString, 2) // 64 1bits
    
    if e != nil {
        return false, e
    }
    result := val & zeroTest
    switch {
        case result == zeroes:
            return true, nil
        case result != zeroes:
            return false, nil
    }
    
    return false, os.NewError("")
}
```

My current problem is I'm having alot of type conversion issues. For example, I am only able to operate on the *int64* type, because that's what *strconv.Btoi64* returns. Another issue that I'm also looking at is that the hash function returns as a byte array, and I have no idea how to convert that into an *int64*.

Below is my current hash code -

```
hasher := sha1.New()
baseCollisionString := "BASE COLLISION STRING"
nonce := "12345"
hasher.Write([]byte(strings.Join(baseCollisionString, nonce)))
testCollision := hasher.Sum()
// Somehow I must convert the first x bits of testCollision into an int64 type, so I can use partialAllZeroes with it
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go so this may be normal, but why are strings involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following code (the function `partialAllZeroes` should run much faster):

```
package main

import "crypto/sha1"

func partialAllZeroes(zeroCount uint8, b []byte) bool {
    i := 0
    for zeroCount >= 8 {
        if b[i] != 0 {
            return false
        }
        i++
        zeroCount -= 8
    }

    var mask byte
    switch zeroCount {
    case 0: mask = 0x00
    case 1: mask = 0x01
    case 2: mask = 0x03
    case 3: mask = 0x07
    case 4: mask = 0x0f
    case 5: mask = 0x1f
    case 6: mask = 0x3f
    case 7: mask = 0x7f
    }

    return (b[i] & mask) == 0
}

func main() {
    hasher := sha1.New()
    baseCollisionString := "BASE COLLISION STRING"
    nonce := "12345"
    hasher.Write([]byte(baseCollisionString + nonce))
    testCollision := hasher.Sum()
    partialAllZeroes(100, testCollision)
}
```

Comment: If `zeroCount` is 10, `b` has to start with 10 zero bits. 8 bits form 1 byte, so `b` has to start with a zero byte followed by 2 zero bits (8+2=10). | If `zeroCount` is 20, `b` has to start with 2 zero bytes followed by 4 zero bits (2*8+4=20).

Comment: mask := 0xFF>>uint(8-zeroCount)
this will yield the same as the switch case

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [math/big.Int](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) type. It can handle large bit sets. It has the [SetString](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetString) method which also handles binary (like `"0b101010"`). With fmt.Printf or Sprintf one can use the `%b` verb to get a binary text string back from it.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to upgrade to the latest weekly (since yesterday RC1).
The "go fix" command will help you in the transition.

Then using strconv pkg:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
        "reflect"
)

func main() {
        a := []byte{ '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1' }

        b, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(a[:3]), 2, 64)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        fmt.Println(b, reflect.TypeOf(b))
}
```

Comment: it's nice to know another new go function was implemented though